# Turn data from column into list

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel file with a column of numbers. I need to take data from this specific column and put them somewhere else (eg somewhere like a Word document) in list format. For example:

```
123456789; 234567891; 23445656; xxx; yyy; zzz; itp.
```

Anyone?

Comment: When you say "somewhere else", do you mean somewhere else on the spreadsheet? Or do you want to output a list to something like a Word document?

Comment: in something like a Word document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your column of data and paste as unformatted text into Word. Then replace ^p with `;`.

Comment: just like that, heh, thanks, i forgot about unformatted paste and i still get columns in word

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values from your column to be listed in a cell you can use the following custom function in you workbook.

```
Function CreateList(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim a As String
    For Each cell In Rng
        a = a & "; " & cell.Value
    Next cell
    CreateList = a
End Function
```

This function creates a semicolon-seperated list of the values in a selected range.